# Split string In Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am meeting a trouble when i try spliting a numpy array with *numpy.char.split()*. the return was that strings was sliced into **list type**, whereas i want to return a **numpy array** nested in the numpyarray. the following is its detail:

My code:

```
print('sol')
print(sol)
sol1 = np.char.split(sol,', ')
print('sol1')
print(sol1)
```

Returned Results:

```
sol
[
['D', '', '0,1', '2', '0.6,0.4'], 
['I', '', '0,1', '2', '0.7,0.3'], 
['G', 'D,I', '0,1,2', '2,2,3', '0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.2'],
['S', 'I', '0,1', '2,2', '0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8'], ['L', 'G', '0,1', '3,2', '0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01']]
sol1
[[list(['D']) list(['']) list(['0,1']) list(['2']) list(['0.6,0.4'])]
 [list(['I']) list(['']) list(['0,1']) list(['2']) list(['0.7,0.3'])]
 [list(['G']) list(['D,I']) list(['0,1,2']) list(['2,2,3']) list(['0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.2'])]
 [list(['S']) list(['I']) list(['0,1']) list(['2,2']) list(['0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8'])]
 [list(['L']) list(['G']) list(['0,1']) list(['3,2']) list(['0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01'])]]
```

The result returns i want to be:

```
sol1
[[['D'] [''] ['0,1'] ['2'] ['0.6,0.4']]
 [['I'] [''] ['0,1'] ['2'] ['0.7,0.3']]
 [['G'] ['D,I'] ['0,1,2'] ['2,2,3'] ['0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.2']]
 [['S'] ['I'] ['0,1'] ['2,2'] ['0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8']]
 [['L'] ['G'] ['0,1'] ['3,2'] ['0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01']]]
```

Would everybody help me to solve this issue. Thanks you very much

Comment: numpy.char.split is doing what it is supposed to do - the input needs to be a string or array-like element, and it outputs an array of lists by default

Comment: @Michael could i split an string nesting in a numpy array into a child numpy array by another way?

Comment: `np.reshape(sol, (5,1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 sol1 = np.char.split('sol',', ')
 print(sol1)
 def array_of_lists_to_array(arr):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: np.array(a[0]), -1, arr[..., None])
 array_of_lists_to_array(np.array(['sol'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sol` print looks more like a list than array:

```
In [316]: sol=[ 
     ...: ['D', '', '0,1', '2', '0.6,0.4'],  
     ...: ['I', '', '0,1', '2', '0.7,0.3'],  
     ...: ['G', 'D,I', '0,1,2', '2,2,3', '0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.
     ...: 7,0.5,0.3,0.2'], 
     ...: ['S', 'I', '0,1', '2,2', '0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8'], ['L', 'G', '0,1', '3,2'
     ...: , '0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01']]                                       
In [317]: print(sol)                                                            
[['D', '', '0,1', '2', '0.6,0.4'], ['I', '', '0,1', '2', '0.7,0.3'], ['G', 'D,I', '0,1,2', '2,2,3', '0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.2'], ['S', 'I', '0,1', '2,2', '0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8'], ['L', 'G', '0,1', '3,2', '0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01']]
```

In either case we can apply `np.char.split`.  With that 2 char split, none of the strings is split, but all are turned into 1 element lists; and it's an object dtype array:

```
In [318]: np.char.split(sol,', ')                                               
Out[318]: 
array([[list(['D']), list(['']), list(['0,1']), list(['2']),
        list(['0.6,0.4'])],
       [list(['I']), list(['']), list(['0,1']), list(['2']),
        list(['0.7,0.3'])],
       [list(['G']), list(['D,I']), list(['0,1,2']), list(['2,2,3']),
        list(['0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.2'])],
       [list(['S']), list(['I']), list(['0,1']), list(['2,2']),
        list(['0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8'])],
       [list(['L']), list(['G']), list(['0,1']), list(['3,2']),
        list(['0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01'])]], dtype=object)
```

as an array `sol` is already (5,5):

```
In [319]: np.array(sol).shape                                                   
Out[319]: (5, 5)
```

we can simply reshape it to "embed" each string in an array dimension:

```
In [320]: np.reshape(sol, (5,5,1))                                              
Out[320]: 
array([[['D'],
        [''],
        ['0,1'],
        ['2'],
        ['0.6,0.4']],

       [['I'],
        [''],
        ['0,1'],
        ['2'],
        ['0.7,0.3']],

       [['G'],
        ['D,I'],
        ['0,1,2'],
        ['2,2,3'],
        ['0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.08,0.02,0.05,0.25,0.7,0.5,0.3,0.2']],

       [['S'],
        ['I'],
        ['0,1'],
        ['2,2'],
        ['0.95,0.05,0.2,0.8']],

       [['L'],
        ['G'],
        ['0,1'],
        ['3,2'],
        ['0.1,0.9,0.4,0.6,0.99,0.01']]], dtype='<U51')
```

split on comma (without space) produces lists of varying length:

```
In [325]: np.char.split(sol,',')                                                
Out[325]: 
array([[list(['D']), list(['']), list(['0', '1']), list(['2']),
        list(['0.6', '0.4'])],
       [list(['I']), list(['']), list(['0', '1']), list(['2']),
        list(['0.7', '0.3'])],
       [list(['G']), list(['D', 'I']), list(['0', '1', '2']),
        list(['2', '2', '3']),
        list(['0.3', '0.4', '0.3', '0.9', '0.08', '0.02', '0.05', '0.25', '0.7', '0.5', '0.3', '0.2'])],
       [list(['S']), list(['I']), list(['0', '1']), list(['2', '2']),
        list(['0.95', '0.05', '0.2', '0.8'])],
       [list(['L']), list(['G']), list(['0', '1']), list(['3', '2']),
        list(['0.1', '0.9', '0.4', '0.6', '0.99', '0.01'])]], dtype=object)
```

docs for `char.split`:

> For each element in `a`, return a **list** of the words in the
> string, using `sep` as the delimiter string.

Comment: -thanks @hpauli, so inteading split numpy.char.spit, i created a list by function sol_list = var.split(','), and put sol = numpy.array(sol_list).

Comment: Using `numpy` for strings doesn't have any speed advantages over lists.